# UI size is bigger on lower res phones, although I'm using DP?

Tags: android

I'm making this simple UI. It fits nicely on the **Nexus 5X (emulator)(1920x1080)**.
But when I'm running the app on the **Galaxy Nexus (emulator)(1280x720)**, the UI doesnt seem to resize which causes it not fitting on the screen. As you can see, I'm using for the sizes only DP's. What am I doing wrong?

**Nexus 5X:**

[image: nexus 5x]

**Galaxy Nexus:**

[image: galaxy nexus]

I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            style="@style/EditValues"
            android:hint="num1"/>

        <EditText
            style="@style/EditValues"
            android:hint="num2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test123333333"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/OperatorButton"
            android:text="+"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/OperatorButton"
            android:text="-"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/OperatorButton"
            android:text="*"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/OperatorButton"
            android:text="%"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="EditValues">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">50dp</item>
</style>

<style name="OperatorButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">50dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `android:weight`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a different dimensions for a different screens sizes.

```
<style name="OperatorButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/operator_btn_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/operator_btn_height</item>
    ....
```

Then create additional values directories values-ldpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi ...
and add dimens.xml files with different values for operator_btn_width etc.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">100dp</dimen>
    ...
```

Dimensions: http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what dp is.  1 Dp is 1/160th of an inch.  It allows you to make sure that an item is the same physical size across all devices- for example an item is always 1 inch wide or always has a quarter inch of padding.  But if a screen is bigger it obviously has more dp than a smaller screen.    You need to then use different sizes or even entirely different layouts for smaller devices if things don't fit.

Answer (score 1):

100dp is obviously going to take up more room on a smaller screen with a smaller resolution.

This is where you need different values in different folders ie `styles-hdpi`, `styles-xhdpi`,`styles-xxhdpi`

Comment: Isnt that the purpose of dp? That it adjusts to every screen? If I need to make a different for every dpi, cant I just use px then?